# WebView - load a new URL/File after X seconds, ad infinitum

Tags: java, android, html, android-webview

I need to be able to load a URL/File in a WebView and then after X number of seconds, load another URL/File (e.g. stored in an array)

I can succesfully load web page 1, but when I put a Thread.sleep() call after the first .loadURL() method, followed by a new .loadURL() with a new file reference, running the app, the first file does not display, but jumps to the second.

Code:

```
file = new File(file_1.html");
webView.loadUrl("file:///" + file.getAbsolutePath());

try {
    Thread.sleep(1000*10); //  10 seconds
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

file = new File(file_2.html");
webView.loadUrl("file:///" + file.getAbsolutePath());
```

As you can see, this is not in a loop, as that is my other problem, I have no idea how to implement this into a loop (I at least wanted to get this bit working before I tackled the loop)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute your code in a Thread or a Handler

```
file = new File(file_1.html");
webView.loadUrl("file:///" + file.getAbsolutePath());

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                file = new File(file_2.html");
                webView.loadUrl("file:///" + file.getAbsolutePath());
            }

        }, 1000);
```

OR

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //task 1...
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    //task 2...
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {

            }
        }
};

t.start();
```

with a timer:

```
timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new MyTask(), 0, 5000);

class MyTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            file = new File("file_1.html");
            webView.loadUrl("file:///" + file.getAbsolutePath());

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000 * 10); // 10 seconds
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            file = new File("file_2.html");
            webView.loadUrl("file:///" + file.getAbsolutePath());

        }
    }
```

Comment: How could this be implemented into a loop? Also, i need to be able to vary the time delay. I have been looking into the Timer class, is that a good place to start?

Comment: What do you want exactly to do?

Comment: Yes you can use a timer if you want repeat your task. no problem.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear :) I need to loop through an ArrayList, that would consist of the filename and the number of seconds to view it. How can I use a Timer when the time changes? Would I use the single timer task, inside the loop?